# Is there a JSlint compatbile way of getting a php variable into javascript?

Tags: javascript, jslint

JSLint is giving me this error (as well as a couple others for the other various bits on Line 7. They all related to how i am pushing that php object into my javascript. Is there a way to do this better that would make JSLint happy?

php

```
$postinfo = json_encode($posts);
```

javascript

```
Line 7: var fullpostsinfo = <?php echo $postinfo ?>;
Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'.
```

Comment: No, because that's not (even _potentially_) valid JavaScript until run through PHP.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the answer. thanks

Comment: SuperKludge: `var fullpostsinfo = eval('<?php echo $postinfo ?>');` This will of course break your code, if you have single quotes in your JSON. And of course you would have to wrap it in `/*jslint evil:false*/` .

Answer (score 0):

No. jslint can only check valid JavaScript code, and does not support (or evaluate) PHP. You would have to paste the generated pure JavaScript code into jslint.